# How to add em-dash in listings environment?

Tags: listings, punctuation

I’m writing the documentation for some piece of code. In it a string containing an em-dash is defined, and I’d like to quote it to show an example of the defined object.

The trouble is the em-dash, which I can’t set in the listings environment. The MWE below shows what I’ve tried so far. Typing “---” prints just three hyphens, `\emdash{}` doesn’t print anything at all, escaping the listings environment *does* print the em-dash, but it creates trouble with the string formatting: The space characters are not displayed as they should (like in example 1).

So the question boils down to: How do I set an em-dash in a listings environment, and if that is impossible, how do I escape the listings environment in a way that doesn’t change the surrounding string?

Here’s the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\lstdefinestyle{java}{
  language          = java,
  stringstyle       = \color{red}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=java,escapechar=!]
pro: {
    descr1: " -- This is some text",
    descr2: " !{\color{red}---}! Here is some more text",
    descr3: " !\emdash{}! And a third version",
    descr4: " !{\color{red}—}! No. 4",
    descr5: " !{\color{red}\textemdash}! No. 5",
    descr6: " \textemdash No. 6"
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, that doesn’t change anything. If I use it unescaped, the listing just prints the characters. If I escape the listing, it looks like in descr4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `literate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\lstdefinestyle{java}{
  language    = java,
  stringstyle = \color{red},
  literate    ={--}{\textendash}1 {---}{\textemdash}2,
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=java]
pro: {
    descr1: " -- This is some text",
    descr2: " --- Here is some more text",
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I don’t need to tell you that this is exactly what I was looking for, but If future beginners look at this question, I’d like to hint them at chapter [6.4 of the listtings documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf). The command works because it replaces “---“ with the character which is produced by ``\textemdash``. The 2 specifies that the replacement character takes two places.